# Unit-Testing Entity Framework 6 with SQLite Inmemory database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

Actually I'm migrating unit-tests from a .NET Core project into a .NET Framework project. Before, I migrated a project using EF Core into a project using EF 6.

Now I want to use my DBContext for my unit-tests. I configured it in my .NET Core Unit-Test project like here: https://github.com/doubleSlashde/ASPNETCoreExample/blob/master/Tests/RepositoryTests/TestBase.cs . But this only works with EF Core.

**How do I have to configure the DBContext now in my Unit-Test project (.NET Framework 4.6)?**
**Prerequisite** is that I can use **Full-Text-Search**. For SQLite I used one of the FTS-Extensions.

Comment: Hi, Have you ever found an elegant solution for this please?